# How to change status colours in Skype for Business 2016

Tags: colors, accessibility, skype-for-business

I'm colour blind, and find it *impossible* to tell the difference between the colours for 'Available' and 'Away' in Skype for Business 2016:

[image: Status colours]

Is there any way to change these, on a per-client basis? I'm hoping that maybe these colours are defined in the registry or a local config file.

Comment: As far as I can tell they're fixed. The only thing I know about is that you can setup a custom presence XML file but that only allows you to change the text, not the color. Available is green, Away is yellow. You can also setup your client to display that text in your contact list but (as far as I can tell) not other instances like Outlook or SharePoint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not yet possible. However a feature request exists for that topic on the official platform for Skype feature requests. So you might wish raise the feature request here[here](https://www.skypefeedback.com/forums/299913-generally-available/suggestions/15084129-color-blindness). Then Microsoft might  include that in a further product or might give you an another answer which the community here couldn´t give you.